# Using intent for sending SMS on Button click from widget

Tags: android, button, click, widget

Ok this is code for my widget. I have two buttons, that are making calls when clicking on them. I want to implement three more buttons for sending SMS, but i can't implement intent for that... I my main app I use smsmanager function ....

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {

        //Timer timer = new Timer();
        //timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), 1, 1000);
        String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

            Intent callIntent1  = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
            Uri.parse("tel:*100" + encodedHash));
            Intent callIntent2  = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
                Uri.parse("tel:*200*1" + encodedHash));

            PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = 
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent1, 0);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = 
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent2, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener to the button
            RemoteViews views1 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            views1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent1);

            RemoteViews views2 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            views2.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent2);

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current App Widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views1);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the smsmanager as follows:

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, null, "Hello world", null, null, null);
```

In addition to your code I would suggest you to override onReceive() method in the WidgetProvider in order to handle sending SMS. The basic implementation could look like this:

First in onUpdate():

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
intent.setAction(ACTION_SEND_SMS);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

And then:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SEND_SMS)) {
        SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sm.sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, null, "Hello world", null, null, null);
    }
}
```

And in the Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.packagename.WidgetProvider" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="com.packagename.ACTION_SEND_SMS"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

Hope that helps

**edited:**

First define list of messages. There are many ways - in this example you can store them in the string array:

```
String[] messages = new String[]{"Message for button 1", "Message for button 2", "Message for button 3"};
String number = "12344444454" // recipient's mobile number
```

Initialize SmsManager:

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
```

Now add onClick listener to your buttons:

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourbutton1);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourbutton2);
Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourbutton3);

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Sending message 1
        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, messages[0], null, null, null);
    }
});

button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Sending message 2
        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, messages[1], null, null, null);
    }
});

button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Sending message 3
        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, messages[2], null, null, null);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null); ;

But this tu variables are underlined and says error "can't resolve to variable" And i need to send three different messages to the same number, and messages are predefined, and not entered by user ??

Comment: Yeah, but i need to send message that depends on pressed button, I have three buttons for messages, and one message is for one button, and not all three messages in the same time :)

Comment: Tnahks. Sorry but ih have new question, where do i need to put this code ?? (in xml that belongs to widget activity, or in xml of my app main activity?? )

Comment: That depends where your buttons are located