# Message will not be sent to mobile

Tags: android

```
send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    sendSms("9500518057","message");

}

private void sendSms(String phno, String message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("PhoneNumber",phno);
    Log.v("MEssage", message);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, new Intent(mContext, Object.class), 0);
    SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phno, null, message, pi, null);
    }
});
```

In this code when I'm clicking the button to send a message it didn't show any response. Also can anyone please tell when click a button it ll only send a confirmation message to particular number. I didn't asked for sending message. i asked for message alert. Is there any methods, please help me

Comment: use notification manager

Comment: You Can Show A `Toast` Or `AlertBox` after sending the message .

Comment: @Madhavi how to use notification manager

Comment: See if this link can help you out somehow.....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988443/i-received-errorr-when-trying-to-send-a-message/13988580#comment19305519_13988580

Comment: i posted code, check it once

Answer (score 0):

updated

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, null, "Hello world", null, null, null);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6996255/760489

Comment: this will open new message prompt, but i asked for sending message alert without asking any prompt

Comment: did you have enable user permission in androidmanifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code    

private static final int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID = 0;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {    

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        final Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "New Alert, Click Me!",
        System.currentTimeMillis());

        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        CharSequence contentTitle = "Open App";

        CharSequence contentText = "hi";
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(YourActivity.this,0,notifyIntent,android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context,contentTitle, contentText, intent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID,notifyDetails);

     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you declare the permission on your apps manifest.xml file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```